# LLVM get values of array literal from GlobalVariable

Tags: llvm

Say an array is declared as follows in LLVM IR:

```
...
@values = local_unnamed_addr constant [6 x i32] [i32 0, i32 1, i32 8, i32 27, i32 64, i32 125], align 16
...
```

This will show up when calling `getGlobalList()` on a `Module` object. How do I get the literal values {0, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125} from the `GlobalVariable*` representing `values`?

Comment: Take a look at `extractvalue` here https://releases.llvm.org/3.3/docs/LangRef.html#insertvalue-instruction

Answer (score 1):

First, you get the `[6 x i32] [i32 0, i32 1, i32 8, i32 27, i32 64, i32 125]` by calling `getInitializer()`, then do `cast<ConstantDataArray>()` and finally use `getElement*` methods.

See http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantDataSequential.html